# Field injection in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, cdi

I understand why [Field Injection of CDI beans is not recommended in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-field-injection-cons) (via `@Autowired` annotation). In Quarkus, however, this is [a common practice](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#what-does-a-bean-look-like) (via `@Inject` annotation).

Why is Field Injection of CDI beans not an issue in Quarkus?

Comment: Quarkus injection is an implementation of the CDI (Context and Dependency Injection) specification in which field injection has always been standard and supported.
For reference, here is a link to CDI specification - https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0

Comment: And Spring (Boot) is not? To me, these frameworks solve similar problems, so I suppose similarity until I know better.

Comment: No, as far as I know, Spring uses at most former JSR-330 (which is where `@Inject` comes from) but otherwise has its own set of rules. Some frameworks such as Quarkus offer a bridge layer allowing users to still use Spring annotations  (like  `@Autowired`) if they are used to them but the actual implementation underneath is done via CDI.